# Error in tapply(explanators_sub[, s], chosen, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : arguments must have same length

Tags: r

I know this question has been asked already but I do not have a `tapply` function in my code. Everything is actually totally new for me. I keep receiving this message after the line explanators  = database[,c("gender","age","edu")]:

> Error in tapply(explanators_sub[, s], chosen, mean, na.rm = TRUE) :    arguments must have same length.

But I do not know what to do. I understand it's a problem of length in the data.

I tried:

```
choiceVar    = database$chosen_veh [,c],
explanators  = database[,c("gender","age","edu")]
```

But it is obviously wrong.

```
library(apollo)
library(readr)

### Clear memory
rm(list = ls())

# ################################################################# #
#### LOAD DATA AND APPLY ANY TRANSFORMATIONS                     ####
# ################################################################# #

database = read_delim("EV.txt", "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
database$rowID =  1:nrow(database)


### Initialise code
apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control = list(
  modelName  ="first_MNL",
  modelDescr ="Simple MNL model on EV car choice SP data",
  indivID    ="rowID",
  panelData = FALSE
)


# ################################################################# #
#### ANALYSIS OF CHOICES                                         ####
# ################################################################# #

choiceAnalysis_settings <- list(
  alternatives = c(E=1, H=2, P=3),
  avail        = list(E=1, H=1, P=1),
  choiceVar    = database$chosen_veh,
  explanators  = database[,c("gender","age","edu")]
)

apollo_choiceAnalysis(choiceAnalysis_settings, apollo_control, database)

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL PARAMETERS                                     ####
# ################################################################# #

### Vector of parameters, including any that are kept fixed in estimation
apollo_beta=c(asc_E      = 0,
              asc_H      = 0,
              asc_P      = 0)

### Vector with names (in quotes) of parameters to be kept fixed at their starting value in apollo_beta, use apollo_beta_fixed = c() if none
apollo_fixed = c("asc_P")

# ################################################################# #
#### GROUP AND VALIDATE INPUTS                                   ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL AND LIKELIHOOD FUNCTION                        ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
  
  ### Attach inputs and detach after function exit
  apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
  on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))
  
  ### Create list of probabilities P
  P = list()
  
  ### List of utilities: these must use the same names as in mnl_settings, order is irrelevant
  V = list()
  V[['E']]  = asc_E  
  V[['H']]  = asc_H   
  V[['P']]  = asc_P  
  
  ### Define settings for MNL model component
  mnl_settings = list(
    alternatives  = c(E=1, H=2, P=3), 
    avail         = list(E=1, H=1, P=1), 
    choiceVar     = chosen_veh,
    V             = V
  )
  
  ### Compute probabilities using MNL model
  P[['model']] = apollo_mnl(mnl_settings, functionality)
  
  ### Take product across observation for same individual
  #P = apollo_panelProd(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  
  ### Prepare and return outputs of function
  P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  return(P)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
# ################################################################# #

model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL OUTPUTS                                               ####
# ################################################################# #

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO SCREEN)                               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_modelOutput(model)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO FILE, using model name)               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_saveOutput(model)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
The data base is quite big but I could insert it in here if needed.

Comment: Perhaps there is a `tapply` statement in one of the functions you are using. After what line does the error occur?

Comment: It occurs after the analysis of choices so after the line explanators  = database[,c("gender","age","edu")]
)

Comment: So probably in the function `apollo_choiceAnalysis`? Make sure your variable names are correct when you put them in the `choiceAnalysis`_settings list.